# Fuzzy match in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Does C# has its own library for Fuzzy match(Fuzzy Search) or a method that can be used directly from .net libraries?

Comment: You could use a Regular Expression.

Comment: Regular Expressions arent very fuzzy

Comment: Similar / duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480/fuzzy-text-sentences-titles-matching-in-c AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83777/are-there-any-fuzzy-search-or-string-similarity-functions-libraries-written-for-c

Comment: Also see this (later) question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19123506/4858

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current versions don't have it built in.

I have seen and used Soundex (a method for fuzzy matching)  operations for this in the past.  Here's an article on how to implement Soundex in .Net.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Soundex.aspx

Comment: Soundex gives pretty awful results compared to Levenshtein.

Comment: Thanks.  I've bookmarked this because I want to try the Levenshtein next time I have a need for such logic.

Answer (score 11):

Not a library, but check out the Levenshtein edit distance algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

It's well known and established and excellent for fuzzy matching text. There are many other examples out there besides the link i provided in case it doesn't suit you: [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHNB_enUS330US330&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=levenshtein+distance+C%23)

Comment: I know  Levenshtein edit distance algorithm and I already used it but I'm wondering if .net has one.

Comment: Not built in. Not as of 3.5 anyway. Though it's fairly trivial to implement as is. Why not just reuse what you already know? Btw. You can add it as an extension method and make it feel like a .Net library function. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If its for a kindof "did you mean" function you could have a look at [Lorenzo Stoakes C# implementation](http://www.codegrunt.co.uk/2010/11/02/C-Sharp-Norvig-Spelling-Corrector.html) of Peter [Norvig's Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

If you need more elaborate search features like ranking and such, you could also take at look at [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)