# Fuzzy string mapping

Tags: c#, algorithm, fuzzy-search

I have an already existing string of manually mapped geographic regions as follows:

```
Czech Republic-Construction     Emerging      CEEMEA            CEEMEA
Czech Republic-Residential      Emerging      CEEMEA            CEEMEA
Czech-Slovakia                  Emerging      CEEMEA            CEEMEA
Daiichi Sankyo US               Developed     North America     North America
Dailian                         Emerging      China             Asia
Daimaru                         Developed     Japan             Japan
Dairy products                  Other         Other             Other
Dalian                          Emerging      China             Asia
```

So basically as you can see, I am mapping such regions to proper geographic locations and companies if any to 'Other'. The new regions that I encounter, have spell mistakes, so i use a set of algorithms to check if I have encountered some strings which are close enough and already mapped, if so, i copy the mapping to the new regions.

The following is the way I have used a set of algorithms.

```
//Levenshtein-Distance
if(LevenshteinDistance == 1) 
    Match string to existing entry.
else if(LevenshteinDistance == 2)
    if(Jaro-Winkler > 0.85) 
        Match string to existing entry.
else if(LevenshteinDistance == 3)
    if(WildCardMatching)
        if(jaro-Winkler)
            Match String to existing entry.
        else
            Add String to List for Manual Mapping.
else
    Add String to List for Manual Mapping.
```

Wild Card Matching Algorithm:- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-character-matching/

Jaro-Winkler Algorithm:- [Jaro–Winkler distance algorithm in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123506/jaro-winkler-distance-algorithm-in-c-sharp)

My question is even after this, i can still find entries that are mapped wrong, Eg:- Labor and Gabon. Is there a way to add more algorithm or change the way i am currently using these algorithms to make a better matching flow?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you count number of occurrences of every word? If a word has three or more occurrences you can asume it isn't wrong.

Comment: Thats actually a good solution, only problem is, if i get a region "USA, Africa, Asia, Latin-America" and i Already have something like "USA, Asia, Africa"(not Latin America), which is mapped to North America, Asia, Africa.. but i need to add Latin-America to the mapping as well for the new region.. in this case, your logic might not work..

Comment: but thanks... it will atleast help me get atleast a few more mappings done right and reduce my manual work.. :)