# Optimizing Big Data Comparison Using For Loops

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, optimization

Okay, here's the deal people.  I've got `two text files`.  Each contains `500` lines (sentences).

I've loaded them into `memory` into an array of their own (datatype: string). Let's name the `array A & B`.

Next I get the `first sentence` in `array A`, split it into another `array C` using `SPACE` as a delimiter, so as to get words.

Then for each sentence in `array B`, I split it into an `array D` using `SPACE` as delimiter again to get words,  and compare each word in `array C` with each word in `array D` calculating the percentage match between the two sentences.

I compute the average percentage match of the first sentence in `array A` against all the sentences in `array B`.

Then I store it into an `Array E` which contains all the sentences of `array A` and their average match percentage.

I do what I do with `first sentence` above for EVERY title in array A.

The problem is that it takes around 15 Seconds to process every title in array A.  Is there anyway I can optimize this time to be faster?

**Hardware:** AMD Phenom I 32 bit Quad Core

**CODE:**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Object
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Important File Paths
        Dim titlesFilePath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\titles.txt"
        Dim xmlTitlesFilePath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\extractedTitles.txt"
        Dim stopWordsFilePath As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\stopWords.txt"

        'Import Important Data From Files -> Memory
        Dim titles As Array = FileToArray(titlesFilePath)
        Dim stopWords As Array = FileToArray(stopWordsFilePath)
        Dim xmlDataUnprocessed As Array = FileToArray(xmlTitlesFilePath)

        'Delimters To Filter Titles For
        Dim userDefinedDelimeters(4, 1)

        userDefinedDelimeters(0, 0) = "-"
        userDefinedDelimeters(0, 1) = " "

        userDefinedDelimeters(1, 0) = ","
        userDefinedDelimeters(1, 1) = " "

        userDefinedDelimeters(2, 0) = "—"
        userDefinedDelimeters(2, 1) = " "

        userDefinedDelimeters(3, 0) = "'s"
        userDefinedDelimeters(3, 1) = ""

        userDefinedDelimeters(4, 0) = "'"
        userDefinedDelimeters(4, 1) = " "

        'Declare Important Variables
        Dim xmlData(xmlDataUnprocessed.Length / 2, 1)
        Dim xmlTurn = 0
        Dim xmlDataCount = 0

        'Create Feed Title/URL Array
        For i = 0 To (xmlDataUnprocessed.Length - 1)
            If xmlTurn = 0 Then
                xmlData(xmlDataCount, 0) = xmlDataUnprocessed(i)
                xmlTurn = 1
            Else
                xmlData(xmlDataCount, 1) = xmlDataUnprocessed(i)
                xmlTurn = 0

                xmlDataCount += 1
            End If
        Next


        'CPU-Intensive Stuff Occurs
        Dim xmlTitle As String
        Dim xmlTitleWords As Array
        Dim savedTitleWords As Array
        Dim titleResults(xmlData.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, 1)
        Dim titlePercentageMatch As Integer
        Dim numberOfTitlesMatched As Integer


        For i = 0 To xmlData.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
            Console.WriteLine("Working On Title No. " & i & " Out Of " & xmlData.GetUpperBound(0) - 1)
            titlePercentageMatch = 0
            numberOfTitlesMatched = 0

            xmlTitle = xmlData(i, 0)
            xmlTitle = processTitle(stopWords, userDefinedDelimeters, xmlTitle)
            xmlTitleWords = xmlTitle.Split(" ")

            For Each title In titles
                title = processTitle(stopWords, userDefinedDelimeters, title)
                savedTitleWords = title.split(" ")
                Dim compareResult = compareTitle(xmlTitleWords, savedTitleWords)
                If compareResult > 0 Then
                    titlePercentageMatch += compareResult
                    numberOfTitlesMatched += 1
                End If
            Next

            titleResults(i, 0) = xmlData(i, 0)
            titleResults(i, 1) = (titlePercentageMatch / numberOfTitlesMatched)
        Next

        For i = 0 To titleResults.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
            Console.WriteLine(titleResults(i, 0) & " ---> " & titleResults(i, 1) & vbCrLf)
        Next

        Console.Read()
    End Sub

    Function compareTitle(ByRef xmlTitleWords As Array, ByRef savedTitleWords As Array)
        Dim NumberOfMatches = 0

        For Each xmlWord In xmlTitleWords
            For Each savedWord In savedTitleWords
                If (xmlWord.ToString.ToLower = savedWord.ToString.ToLower) Then
                    NumberOfMatches += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        Return ((NumberOfMatches / xmlTitleWords.Length) * 100)
    End Function

    Function processTitle(ByRef stopWordArray As Array, ByRef delimArray As Array, ByVal title As String)
        title = removeStopWords(stopWordArray, title)
        title = removeDelims(delimArray, title)

        Return title
    End Function

    Function removeStopWords(ByRef stopWordsArray As Array, ByVal sentence As String)
        For i = 0 To stopWordsArray.Length - 1
            If sentence.ToLower.Contains(" " & stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower & " ") = True Then
                sentence = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(sentence, " " & stopWordsArray(i) & " ", " ", 1, -1, Constants.vbTextCompare)
                'ElseIf sentence.ToLower.Contains(stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower & " ") = True Then
                'sentence = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(sentence, stopWordsArray(i) & " ", "", 1, -1, Constants.vbTextCompare)
            End If

            sentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, "\s+", " ")

            Dim Words = sentence.ToLower.Split(" ")

            If Words(0).ToString.ToLower & " " = stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower & " " Then
                sentence = sentence.Remove(0, stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower.Length + 1)
            End If

            Words = sentence.ToLower.Split(" ")
            Dim LastWord = Words(Words.Length - 1)
            'Console.WriteLine(LastWord & "++")

            If " " & LastWord.ToString.ToLower = " " & stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower Then
                sentence = sentence.Remove(sentence.Length - 1 - LastWord.Length, stopWordsArray(i).ToString.ToLower.Length + 1)
            End If

        Next

        sentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, "\s+", " ")

        Return sentence
    End Function

    Function removeDelims(ByRef delimArray As Array, ByVal sentence As String)
        For i = 0 To delimArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
            sentence = sentence.Replace(delimArray(i, 0), delimArray(i, 1))
        Next
        sentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, "\s+", " ")
        Return sentence
    End Function

    Function FileToArray(ByVal filePath As String) As String()
        Dim content As String
        Dim lines As New ArrayList
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader

        ' read the file's lines into an ArrayList
        Try
            sr = New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine())
            Loop
        Finally
            If Not sr Is Nothing Then sr.Close()
        End Try

        ' convert from ArrayList to a String array
        Return CType(lines.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())
    End Function

End Module
```

**Edit:** I hope it's not too confusing. Sorry about that!
**Edit 2:** Provided sauce :P

Comment: You have a bug: `NumberOfMatches / xmlTitleWords.Length` could result in false 100% matches if `savedTitleWords.Length > xmlTitleWords.Length` and `xmlTitleWords` has all of `savedTitleWords`.

Comment: Edit: thanks for the clarification!  Hmmm, the algo definitely needs tweaking :)  Bascially this whole program is for a simple experiment I'm conducting where I'm trying to find titles of articles which are similar to previous articles I needed.  Any suggestion on how to implement such a program? I racked my brains, but this is just the prototyping phase, will need to look more into the matching algo, any help would be super-appreciated :)

Comment: If the current title in your outer loop is *Hello World* and the current title in your inner loop is *Hello World How Are You* then you would get two matches. When you divide two by the length of the outer loop, you get 1 (100%)... but the titles don't match 100%.

Comment: Nice catch! Will have to improve this wretched algo -_-'

Comment: This does sound like an interesting project. Maybe you need a definition of what "similar" is. For example "similar means >= 90% words in common excluding punctuation and unimportant words like *the*". You also might want to make the percentage on a sliding scale depending on title length (e.g. titles with 20 words might be "similar enough" with only 50% in common). I'm curious what percent makes sense. You could do semantic analysis, but that's a whole level of new complexity...

Comment: Indeed, I'm loving trying to work out a decent solution for this.  Basically what I mean by similar is 'theme' similar.  Let's say we've got two titles already in my database 1: **craft.js - a small but powerful javascript framework that helps you to build web applications** and 2: **numeral.js - a javascript library for formatting and manipulating numbers**.  Now if in our stream of data, there is **jim knopf - a small javascript library to create knobs using svg** - the algo should be able to identify this as similar 'themed' to the other ones and filter the non-matching ones.

Comment: currently I am just using this formula: **((# of matching words) / (# of words in bigger string)) * ((# of words in smaller string) / (# of words in bigger string))** which I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2923488/576589 - it's decent but with plenty of falsey results turning up...thinking about building a database with false positives and filtering the results from the formula against the false postives and see how it works out.  If you've got any idea, would be glad to hear them :)

Comment: You might look at [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram). You might want to consider word order. You might also try several algorithms at once, compare results and pick what in your judgement seems to be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic algorithm is **N*M*A<sup>2</sup>** where

- **N** = number of titles in first file
- **M** = number of titles in second file
- **A** = average words per title

If you have 500*500*5<sup>2</sup> you're pushing 6,250,000 case insensitive string compares. But that's if that's all you were doing. Your inner loop calls `processTitle` for every `title` by your outer loop's length. It doesn't need to do that.

### Single Threaded

What you can do is have a pre-processing step that replaces each word with an integer (symbol) that represents that word. For this, you'd use a dictionary to look up the symbol, and if there wasn't one, assign a new unique symbol (e.g. keep an integer counter and use the next value).

You would then have your main processing loop similar to what you had before, but you're instead doing integer comparisons (a lot faster). In fact, you'd want this processing step to *only* do comparisons and collection of statistics. Everything else should be moved out.

### Multi-Threaded

Keep your preprocessing step.

Parallelize your processing step. One way to do this is to use [Parallel.For()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx) for the outermost loop: `Parallel.For(0, xmlData.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, Sub(i) ... End Sub)` where the action is your loop body from above. The TPL will probably balance the load just fine (using your 4 cores evenly).

Another way is to use the task parallel library to spin-up for tasks that operate on 1/4 the data. Then kick off a continuation that uses the results.

Comment: wow! fantastic answer! :)  I've refactored the whole code and moved every processing out of the loops towards the data-generating source.  Managed to bring down processing time of each title to less than  2 seconds :)

Comment: I've been looking into Parallel.ForEach() for the loops, but cannot wrap my head around it.  Could you give me a quick heads up on how to apply Parallel.ForEach() in the above program? Thank you in advance for all you time and help :)

Comment: Actually, `Parallel.For()` might be better in your case and just simply takes the upper and lower bound and an `Action(T)`. I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: thanks for the update! Will implement and provide feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

read only `array B` to memory at once, then read line by line `array A`.

Where applicable use StringBuilder instead of string.

Also, see if you can use parallel processing, ie: Tasks.

As for distance, matching algorithm, you didnt mention what it is and how it does. So hard to say anything about it.

Comment: hmmm, array B is loaded to memory once only, initially at program load.  I'll post the source code.  I let you all examine it.  Mind, it's not really pro-programming from me :P

Comment: you read one file and load to memory at once (slower), read the other file line by line (faster) and compare against the other file in the memory.

Comment: the loading of file is rather quick, withing a 2/3 seconds, that's not really a problem, but the comparison with multiple nested loops and string crunching things make it slow.  I've been testing the program for bottlenecks at every feature implemented.  The nested looping comparison is where it bottlenecks like hell.  Any suggestion?  I've posted the whole source code.

Answer (score 1):

You're slowing yourself down a bit with a few things...

1. `If (xmlWord.ToString.ToLower = savedWord.ToString.ToLower) Then`

   Why not change EVERYTHING to lower case before even putting it into the array?
2. `title = processTitle(stopWords, userDefinedDelimeters, title)`

   Why not do that before loading it into arrays too??

Do all your processing ahead of time, then JUST do the comparisons separately.

Comment: will try to do those things and see if there's any improvements :)