# Fuzzy text search in Python

Tags: python, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I am wondering if there is a Python library can conduct fuzzy text search. For example:

- I have three keywords **"letter"**, **"stamp"**, and **"mail"**.
- I would like to have a function to check if those three words are within
  the same paragraph (or certain distances, one page).
- In addition, those words have to maintain the same order. It is fine that other words appear between those three words.

I have tried fuzzywuzzy which did not solve my problem. Another library, Whoosh, looks powerful, but I did not find the proper function.

Comment: See if this link helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923420/what-is-a-simple-fuzzy-string-matching-algorithm-in-python

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar thanks for the comment. I have checked that post, but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**{1}**
You can do this in `Whoosh 2.7`. It has fuzzy search by adding the plugin `whoosh.qparser.FuzzyTermPlugin`:

> `whoosh.qparser.FuzzyTermPlugin` lets you search for “fuzzy” terms, that is, terms that don’t have to match exactly. The fuzzy term will match any similar term within a certain number of “edits” (character insertions, deletions, and/or transpositions – this is called the “Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance”).

To add the fuzzy plugin:

```
parser = qparser.QueryParser("fieldname", my_index.schema)
parser.add_plugin(qparser.FuzzyTermPlugin())
```

Once you add the fuzzy plugin to the parser, you can specify a fuzzy term by adding a `~` followed by an optional maximum edit distance. If you don’t specify an edit distance, the default is 1.

For example, the following “fuzzy” term query:

```
letter~
letter~2
letter~2/3
```

---

**{2}** To keep words in order, use the Query `whoosh.query.Phrase` but you should replace `Phrase` plugin by `whoosh.qparser.SequencePlugin` that allows you to use fuzzy terms inside a phrase:

```
"letter~ stamp~ mail~"
```

To replace the default phrase plugin with the sequence plugin:

```
parser = qparser.QueryParser("fieldname", my_index.schema)
parser.remove_plugin_class(qparser.PhrasePlugin)
parser.add_plugin(qparser.SequencePlugin())
```

---

**{3}** To allow words between, initialize the `slop` arg in your Phrase query to a greater number:

```
whoosh.query.Phrase(fieldname, words, slop=1, boost=1.0, char_ranges=None)
```

> **slop** – the number of words allowed between each “word” in the phrase; the default of 1 means the phrase must match exactly.

You can also define slop in Query like this:

```
"letter~ stamp~ mail~"~10
```

---

**{4}** Overall solution:

**{4.a}** **Indexer** would be like:

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *

schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), content=TEXT)
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(title=u"First document", content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
writer.add_document(title=u"Third document", content=u"letter first, stamp second, mail third")
writer.add_document(title=u"Fourth document", content=u"stamp first, mail third")
writer.add_document(title=u"Fivth document", content=u"letter first,  mail third")
writer.add_document(title=u"Sixth document", content=u"letters first, stamps second, mial third wrong")
writer.add_document(title=u"Seventh document", content=u"stamp first, letters second, mail third")
writer.commit()
```

**{4.b}** **Searcher** would be like:

```
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser, FuzzyTermPlugin, PhrasePlugin, SequencePlugin

with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    parser = QueryParser(u"content", ix.schema)
    parser.add_plugin(FuzzyTermPlugin())
    parser.remove_plugin_class(PhrasePlugin)
    parser.add_plugin(SequencePlugin())
    query = parser.parse(u"\"letter~2 stamp~2 mail~2\"~10")
    results = searcher.search(query)
    print "nb of results =", len(results)
    for r in results:
        print r
```

That gives the result:

```
nb of results = 2
<Hit {'title': u'Sixth document'}>
<Hit {'title': u'Third document'}>
```

---

**{5}** If you want to set fuzzy search as default without using the syntax `word~n` in each word of the query, you can initialize `QueryParser` like this:

```
 from whoosh.query import FuzzyTerm
 parser = QueryParser(u"content", ix.schema, termclass = FuzzyTerm)
```

Now you can use the query `"letter stamp mail"~10` but keep in mind that `FuzzyTerm` has default edit distance `maxdist = 1`. Personalize the class if you want bigger edit distance:

```
class MyFuzzyTerm(FuzzyTerm):
     def __init__(self, fieldname, text, boost=1.0, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1, constantscore=True):
         super(D, self).__init__(fieldname, text, boost, maxdist, prefixlength, constantscore) 
         # super().__init__() for Python 3 I think
```

---

References:

1. [whoosh.query.Phrase](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html#whoosh.query.Phrase)
2. [Adding fuzzy term queries](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parsing.html?highlight=sequenceplugin#adding-fuzzy-term-queries)
3. [Allowing complex phrase queries](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parsing.html?highlight=sequenceplugin#allowing-complex-phrase-queries)
4. [class whoosh.query.FuzzyTerm](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/query.html#whoosh.query.Term)
5. [qparser module](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/qparser.html)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for writing this self-contained example! Really appreciate your help!