# Name Matching in python

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy, name-matching

We have a third party 'tool' which finds **similar** names and assigns a similarity score between two names.

I am supposed to mimic the tool's behavior as closely as possible.
After searching over internet, gave a shot at distance method.Used [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) for the same.

```
matches = process.extractBests(
    name, 
    choices, 
    score_cutoff=50, 
    scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,
    limit=1 
);
```

It gave results close to the tool result.However there are few outliers - as highlighted below.

[image]

After further searches over internet, I have come to the understand that further refinement will need implementation of machine learning of sort. I am a complete newbie in the machine learning world - so seeking some advice as to where I should attempt at next for further code refinement.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923420/what-is-a-simple-fuzzy-string-matching-algorithm-in-python

Comment: Can I ask what 3rd party tool you were using for the first column?

Comment: @Stpete111 The tool is bridger - https://risk.lexisnexis.com/products/bridger-insight-xg

Comment: Thanks.  Ah ok, so an actual full search solution.  I thought you meant a 3rd-party name-match algorithm to which you have access to implement into your own code.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this package. It is tailor-made for Name Matching
[HMNI Package](https://github.com/Christopher-Thornton/hmni)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Jaccard and Levenshtein algorithms for fuzzy string matching. Both are relatively simple and can be implemented in about 40 or 50 lines of code.

Comment: fuzzywuzzy library mentioned in the question uses Levenshtein similarity