# Getting the closest string match

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

I need a way to compare multiple strings to a test string and return the string that closely resembles it:

```
TEST STRING: THE BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE RED COW

CHOICE A   : THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE GREEN CHICKEN
CHOICE B   : THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE RED COW
CHOICE C   : THE RED FOX JUMPED OVER THE BROWN COW
```

(If I did this correctly) The closest string to the "TEST STRING" should be "CHOICE C".  What is the easiest way to do this?

I plan on implementing this into multiple languages including VB.net, Lua, and JavaScript.  At this point, pseudo code is acceptable.  If you can provide an example for a specific language, this is appreciated too!

Comment: Algorithms that typically do this type of stuff work on determining how many changes it takes to turn an examined string into the target string. Those types of algorithms don't work well at all in a situation like this. I think getting a computer to pull this off will be very tough.

Comment: Levenshtein distance source code in many languages: Java, Ruby, Python, PHP, etc. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: In general, what counts as "closest string" will depend on the similarity measure used, and the penalties used for introducing gaps in the alignment. For example, do you consider "cow" and "chicken" more similar than "cow" and "red" (because they are related concepts), or is it the other way around (because "chicken" has more letters than "cow")? But given a similarity measure and gap penalty, it can be shown that the Levenshtein algorithm below is guaranteed to find you the closest string. Same is true of Needleman-Wunsch and Smith-Waterman (further below).

Comment: Do character grouping, or word grouping. Give it score.

Answer (score 1022, accepted):

I was presented with this problem about a year ago when it came to looking up user entered information about a oil rig in a database of miscellaneous information. The goal was to do some sort of fuzzy string search that could identify the database entry with the most common elements.

Part of the research involved implementing the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm, which determines how many changes must be made to a string or phrase to turn it into another string or phrase.

The implementation I came up with was relatively simple, and involved a weighted comparison of the length of the two phrases, the number of changes between each phrase, and whether each word could be found in the target entry.

The article is on a private site so I'll do my best to append the relevant contents here:

---

Fuzzy String Matching is the process of performing a human-like estimation of the similarity of two words or phrases. In many cases, it involves identifying words or phrases which are most similar to each other. This article describes an in-house solution to the fuzzy string matching problem and its usefulness in solving a variety of problems which can allow us to automate tasks which previously required tedious user involvement.

**Introduction**

The need to do fuzzy string matching originally came about while developing the Gulf of Mexico Validator tool. What existed was a database of known gulf of Mexico oil rigs and platforms, and people buying insurance would give us some badly typed out information about their assets and we had to match it to the database of known platforms. When there was very little information given, the best we could do is rely on an underwriter to "recognize" the one they were referring to and call up the proper information. This is where this automated solution comes in handy.

I spent a day researching methods of fuzzy string matching, and eventually stumbled upon the very useful Levenshtein distance algorithm on Wikipedia.

**Implementation**

After reading about the theory behind it, I implemented and found ways to optimize it. This is how my code looks like in VBA:

```vb
'Calculate the Levenshtein Distance between two strings (the number of insertions,
'deletions, and substitutions needed to transform the first string into the second)
Public Function LevenshteinDistance(ByRef S1 As String, ByVal S2 As String) As Long
    Dim L1 As Long, L2 As Long, D() As Long 'Length of input strings and distance matrix
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, cost As Long 'loop counters and cost of substitution for current letter
    Dim cI As Long, cD As Long, cS As Long 'cost of next Insertion, Deletion and Substitution
    L1 = Len(S1): L2 = Len(S2)
    ReDim D(0 To L1, 0 To L2)
    For i = 0 To L1: D(i, 0) = i: Next i
    For j = 0 To L2: D(0, j) = j: Next j

    For j = 1 To L2
        For i = 1 To L1
            cost = Abs(StrComp(Mid$(S1, i, 1), Mid$(S2, j, 1), vbTextCompare))
            cI = D(i - 1, j) + 1
            cD = D(i, j - 1) + 1
            cS = D(i - 1, j - 1) + cost
            If cI <= cD Then 'Insertion or Substitution
                If cI <= cS Then D(i, j) = cI Else D(i, j) = cS
            Else 'Deletion or Substitution
                If cD <= cS Then D(i, j) = cD Else D(i, j) = cS
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
    LevenshteinDistance = D(L1, L2)
End Function
```

Simple, speedy, and a very useful metric. Using this, I created two separate metrics for evaluating the similarity of two strings. One I call "valuePhrase" and one I call "valueWords". valuePhrase is just the Levenshtein distance between the two phrases, and valueWords splits the string into individual words, based on delimiters such as spaces, dashes, and anything else you'd like, and compares each word to each other word, summing up the shortest Levenshtein distance connecting any two words. Essentially, it measures whether the information in one 'phrase' is really contained in another, just as a word-wise permutation. I spent a few days as a side project coming up with the most efficient way possible of splitting a string based on delimiters.

valueWords, valuePhrase, and Split function:

```vb
Public Function valuePhrase#(ByRef S1$, ByRef S2$)
    valuePhrase = LevenshteinDistance(S1, S2)
End Function

Public Function valueWords#(ByRef S1$, ByRef S2$)
    Dim wordsS1$(), wordsS2$()
    wordsS1 = SplitMultiDelims(S1, " _-")
    wordsS2 = SplitMultiDelims(S2, " _-")
    Dim word1%, word2%, thisD#, wordbest#
    Dim wordsTotal#
    For word1 = LBound(wordsS1) To UBound(wordsS1)
        wordbest = Len(S2)
        For word2 = LBound(wordsS2) To UBound(wordsS2)
            thisD = LevenshteinDistance(wordsS1(word1), wordsS2(word2))
            If thisD < wordbest Then wordbest = thisD
            If thisD = 0 Then GoTo foundbest
        Next word2
foundbest:
        wordsTotal = wordsTotal + wordbest
    Next word1
    valueWords = wordsTotal
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SplitMultiDelims
' This function splits Text into an array of substrings, each substring
' delimited by any character in DelimChars. Only a single character
' may be a delimiter between two substrings, but DelimChars may
' contain any number of delimiter characters. It returns a single element
' array containing all of text if DelimChars is empty, or a 1 or greater
' element array if the Text is successfully split into substrings.
' If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters is true, empty array elements will not occur.
' If Limit greater than 0, the function will only split Text into 'Limit'
' array elements or less. The last element will contain the rest of Text.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function SplitMultiDelims(ByRef Text As String, ByRef DelimChars As String, _
        Optional ByVal IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal Limit As Long = -1) As String()
    Dim ElemStart As Long, N As Long, M As Long, Elements As Long
    Dim lDelims As Long, lText As Long
    Dim Arr() As String

    lText = Len(Text)
    lDelims = Len(DelimChars)
    If lDelims = 0 Or lText = 0 Or Limit = 1 Then
        ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
        Arr(0) = Text
        SplitMultiDelims = Arr
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim Arr(0 To IIf(Limit = -1, lText - 1, Limit))

    Elements = 0: ElemStart = 1
    For N = 1 To lText
        If InStr(DelimChars, Mid(Text, N, 1)) Then
            Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart, N - ElemStart)
            If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then
                If Len(Arr(Elements)) > 0 Then Elements = Elements + 1
            Else
                Elements = Elements + 1
            End If
            ElemStart = N + 1
            If Elements + 1 = Limit Then Exit For
        End If
    Next N
    'Get the last token terminated by the end of the string into the array
    If ElemStart <= lText Then Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart)
    'Since the end of string counts as the terminating delimiter, if the last character
    'was also a delimiter, we treat the two as consecutive, and so ignore the last elemnent
    If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then If Len(Arr(Elements)) = 0 Then Elements = Elements - 1

    ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Elements) 'Chop off unused array elements
    SplitMultiDelims = Arr
End Function
```

**Measures of Similarity**

Using these two metrics, and a third which simply computes the distance between two strings, I have a series of variables which I can run an optimization algorithm to achieve the greatest number of matches. Fuzzy string matching is, itself, a fuzzy science, and so by creating linearly independent metrics for measuring string similarity, and having a known set of strings we wish to match to each other, we can find the parameters that, for our specific styles of strings, give the best fuzzy match results.

Initially, the goal of the metric was to have a low search value for for an exact match, and increasing search values for increasingly permuted measures. In an impractical case, this was fairly easy to define using a set of well defined permutations, and engineering the final formula such that they had increasing search values results as desired.

[image: Fuzzy String Matching Permutations]

In the above screenshot, I tweaked my heuristic to come up with something that I felt scaled nicely to my perceived difference between the search term and result. The heuristic I used for `Value Phrase` in the above spreadsheet was `=valuePhrase(A2,B2)-0.8*ABS(LEN(B2)-LEN(A2))`. I was effectively reducing the penalty of the Levenstein distance by 80% of the difference in the length of the two "phrases". This way, "phrases" that have the same length suffer the full penalty, but "phrases" which contain 'additional information' (longer) but aside from that still mostly share the same characters suffer a reduced penalty. I used the `Value Words` function as is, and then my final `SearchVal` heuristic was defined as `=MIN(D2,E2)*0.8+MAX(D2,E2)*0.2` - a weighted average. Whichever of the two scores was lower got weighted 80%, and 20% of the higher score. This was just a heuristic that suited my use case to get a good match rate. These weights are something that one could then tweak to get the best match rate with their test data.

[image: Fuzzy String Matching Value Phrase]

[image: Fuzzy String Matching Value Words]

As you can see, the last two metrics, which are fuzzy string matching metrics, already have a natural tendency to give low scores to strings that are meant to match (down the diagonal). This is very good.

**Application**
To allow the optimization of fuzzy matching, I weight each metric. As such, every application of fuzzy string match can weight the parameters differently. The formula that defines the final score is a simply combination of the metrics and their weights:

```
value = Min(phraseWeight*phraseValue, wordsWeight*wordsValue)*minWeight
      + Max(phraseWeight*phraseValue, wordsWeight*wordsValue)*maxWeight
      + lengthWeight*lengthValue
```

Using an optimization algorithm (neural network is best here because it is a discrete, multi-dimentional problem), the goal is now to maximize the number of matches. I created a function that detects the number of correct matches of each set to each other, as can be seen in this final screenshot. A column or row gets a point if the lowest score is assigned the the string that was meant to be matched, and partial points are given if there is a tie for the lowest score, and the correct match is among the tied matched strings. I then optimized it. You can see that a green cell is the column that best matches the current row, and a blue square around the cell is the row that best matches the current column. The score in the bottom corner is roughly the number of successful matches and this is what we tell our optimization problem to maximize.

[image: Fuzzy String Matching Optimized Metric]

The algorithm was a wonderful success, and the solution parameters say a lot about this type of problem. You'll notice the optimized score was 44, and the best possible score is 48. The 5 columns at the end are decoys, and do not have any match at all to the row values. The more decoys there are, the harder it will naturally be to find the best match.

In this particular matching case, the length of the strings are irrelevant, because we are expecting abbreviations that represent longer words, so the optimal weight for length is -0.3, which means we do not penalize strings which vary in length. We reduce the score in anticipation of these abbreviations, giving more room for partial word matches to supersede non-word matches that simply require less substitutions because the string is shorter.

The word weight is 1.0 while the phrase weight is only 0.5, which means that we penalize whole words missing from one string and value more the entire phrase being intact. This is useful because a lot of these strings have one word in common (the peril) where what really matters is whether or not the combination (region and peril) are maintained.

Finally, the min weight is optimized at 10 and the max weight at 1. What this means is that if the best of the two scores (value phrase and value words) isn't very good, the match is greatly penalized, but we don't greatly penalize the worst of the two scores. Essentially, this puts emphasis on requiring *either* the valueWord or valuePhrase to have a good score, but not both. A sort of "take what we can get" mentality.

It's really fascinating what the optimized value of these 5 weights say about the sort of fuzzy string matching taking place. For completely different practical cases of fuzzy string matching, these parameters are very different. I've used it for 3 separate applications so far.

While unused in the final optimization, a benchmarking sheet was established which matches columns to themselves for all perfect results down the diagonal, and lets the user change parameters to control the rate at which scores diverge from 0, and note innate similarities between search phrases (which could in theory be used to offset false positives in the results)

[image: Fuzzy String Matching Benchmark]

**Further Applications**

This solution has potential to be used anywhere where the user wishes to have a computer system identify a string in a set of strings where there is no perfect match. (Like an approximate match vlookup for strings).

---

So what you should take from this, is that you probably want to use a combination of high level heuristics (finding words from one phrase in the other phrase, length of both phrases, etc) along with the implementation of the Levenshtein distance algorithm. Because deciding which is the "best" match is a heuristic (fuzzy) determination - you'll have to come up with a set of weights for any metrics you come up with to determine similarity.

With the appropriate set of heuristics and weights, you'll have your comparison program quickly making the decisions that you would have made.

Comment: Bonus: If anyone wants to include additional metrics into their weighted heuristic, (since I only provided 3 which weren't all that linearly independent) - here is a whole list on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Comment: Awesome! You may be able to speed this up quite a bit by replacing the 2D-matrix-based code in LevenshteinDistance() with something like the 1D approach as used in [Chas Emerick’s Java implementation](http://www.merriampark.com/ldjava.htm).

Comment: If S2 has a lot of words (and creating many small objects is not prohibitively slow in your language of choice) a trie can speed things up. [Fast and Easy Levenshtein distance using a Trie](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114) is a great article about tries.

Comment: @Alain how can I cite this if I use this? Is there a source for the paper/article?

Comment: @Mathguy I'm afraid it's not published anywhere reputable. You can reference my linkedin (https://www.linkedin.com/in/alainbryden#publications) but that just links back to this page.

Comment: @Alain This is an interesting approach! I am just playing a bit with your idea (in C++) but do not understand one point, the value of `valuePhrase`. If I see right in your code, its the return value of the Levenshtein distance function. How come it is a double/float value in the 'abcd efgh' search table? Levenshtein distance is an integer value and I cannot see further calculations in your code that makes it a float. What do I miss?

Comment: @AndreasW.Wylach Great observation. The VBA I showed was just to compute the Levenshtein distance, but the heuristic I used in my spreadsheet was `=valuePhrase(A2,B2)-0.8*ABS(LEN(B2)-LEN(A2))` So I was reducing the penalty of the levenstein distance by 80% of the difference in the length of the two "phrases". This way, "phrases" that have the same length suffer the full penalty, but "phrases" which contain 'additional information' (longer) but aside from that still mostly share the same characters suffer a reduced penalty.

Comment: @Alain Thanks for getting back to my question, I appreciate that. Your explanation makes things clearer now. Meanwhile I implemented a value_phrase method that gets a little deeper into analysing the tokens of a phrase a bit more, that is the order/positions of the phrase tokens, non-query token sequences and it accepts a bit more fuzziness when it comes to something like "acbd" compared to "abcd". Tendency of the phrase_value scores equals yours, but get a bit lower here and there. Once again, great workout and it gave me inspiration for the fuzzy search algorithm!

Comment: You can (now) make this process a tad easier by using a library that implements most string similarity and distance algorithms in Python: https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity (great post btw!)

Comment: Excellent, even I have been given a research to do exactly the same, from two table entries, find the position where the string has mismatch, get them printed in another table and correct it. This is great

Comment: @Alain I know this is a very old post, but I just leveraged this algorithm in a tool I built and I think I may have found a flaw/bug, though it could be my VB is too rusty. It seems to me you want to force the outer loop in valueWords to be the longer of the two arrays. Consider the case of comparing words1 'single' to words2 'this is a sentence containing single'. I believe the algorithm as implemented would show this as a perfect match.

Comment: @Alain thanks for this. It's very helpful, however in the optimisation/neural network diagram, what is `lengthValue` , the variable that is multiplied by -0.3? I can't seem to get the same values as your diagram (WORLDWIDE_ALL_PERIL and Worldwide All Perils are returning 8 instead of 11 for instance), which makes me wonder if I've implemented something wrongly (I'm trying to do this in Java)

Comment: @clattenburgcake it's been a while, but I believe `lengthValue` was simply `abs(len(string1) - len(string2))` (the difference in the length of the two strings).

Answer (score 94):

This problem turns up all the time in bioinformatics. The accepted answer above (which was great by the way) is known in bioinformatics as the Needleman-Wunsch (compare two strings) and Smith-Waterman (find an approximate substring in a longer string) algorithms. They work great and have been workhorses for decades.

**But what if you have a million strings to compare?** That's a trillion pairwise comparisons, each of which is O(n*m)! Modern DNA sequencers easily generate a *billion* short DNA sequences, each about 200 DNA "letters" long. Typically, we want to find, for each such string, the best match against the human genome (3 billion letters). Clearly, the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm and its relatives will not do.

This so-called "alignment problem" is a field of active research. The most popular algorithms are currently able to find inexact matches between 1 billion short strings and the human genome in a matter of hours on reasonable hardware (say, eight cores and 32 GB RAM).

Most of these algorithms work by quickly finding short exact matches (seeds) and then extending these to the full string using a slower algorithm (for example, the Smith-Waterman). The reason this works is that we are really only interested in a few close matches, so it pays off to get rid of the 99.9...% of pairs that have nothing in common.

How does finding exact matches help finding *inexact* matches? Well, say we allow only a single difference between the query and the target. It is easy to see that this difference must occur in either the right or left half of the query, and so the other half must match exactly. This idea can be extended to multiple mismatches and is the basis for the [ELAND](http://www.illumina.com/documents/products/technotes/technote_eland_variantcalling_improvements.pdf) algorithm commonly used with Illumina DNA sequencers.

There are many very good algorithms for doing exact string matching. Given a query string of length 200, and a target string of length 3 billion (the human genome), we want to find any place in the target where there is a substring of length k that matches a substring of the query exactly. A simple approach is to begin by indexing the target: take all k-long substrings, put them in an array and sort them. Then take each k-long substring of the query and search the sorted index. <strike>Sort and</strike> search can be done in O(log n) time.

But storage can be a problem. An index of the 3 billion letter target would need to hold 3 billion pointers and 3 billion k-long words. It would seem hard to fit this in less than several tens of gigabytes of RAM. But amazingly we can greatly compress the index, using the [Burrows-Wheeler transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows-Wheeler_transform), and it will still be efficiently queryable. An index of the human genome can fit in less than 4 GB RAM. This idea is the basis of popular sequence aligners such as [Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) and [BWA](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/).

Alternatively, we can use a [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array), which stores only the pointers, yet represents a simultaneous index of all suffixes in the target string (essentially, a simultaneous index for all possible values of k; the same is true of the Burrows-Wheeler transform). A suffix array index of the human genome will take 12 GB of RAM if we use 32-bit pointers.

The links above contain a wealth of information and links to primary research papers. The ELAND link goes to a PDF with useful figures illustrating the concepts involved, and shows how to deal with insertions and deletions.

Finally, while these algorithms have basically solved the problem of (re)sequencing single human genomes (a billion short strings), DNA sequencing technology improves even faster than Moore's law, and we are fast approaching trillion-letter datasets. For example, there are currently projects underway to sequence the genomes of [10,000 vertebrate species](http://www.genome10k.org/), each a billion letters long or so. Naturally, we will want to do pairwise inexact string matching on the data...

Comment: Really good run-down. A couple of corrections: Sorting the infixes takes O(n) at least, not O(log n). And since O(log n) search is actually too slow in practice, you’d normally build an additional table to get O(1) lookup (q-gram index). Furthermore, I’m not sure why you treat this differently from the suffix array – it’s just an optimisation of the latter, no (sorting fixed-length infixes instead of suffixes since we don’t actually need more than a fixed length).

Comment: Furthermore, these algorithms are still impractical for *de novo* sequencing. They’ve solved the sequencing of human genomes only insofar as we have a reference sequence that can be used to map against. But for de novo assembly other algorithms are needed (well, there are some aligners which are based on mapping but stitching the contigs together is a whole ’nother problem). Finally, shameless plug: [my bachelor thesis](http://madr.at/my/bachelor) contains a detailed description of the ELAND algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I edited out the error. The reason I started by describing the fixed-length array was because it's easy to understand. Suffix arrays and BWT are a bit harder to grasp, but actually we do sometimes want to use an index with different values of k. For example, [STAR](http://gingeraslab.cshl.edu/STAR/STARintro.htm) uses suffix arrays to efficiently find *spliced* alignments. This is of course useful for aligning RNA to the genome.

Answer (score 30):

I contest that choice B is closer to the test string, as it's only 4 characters(and 2 deletes) from being the original string. Whereas you see C as closer because it includes both brown and red. It would, however, have a greater edit distance.

There is an algorithm called [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which measures the edit distance between two inputs.

[Here](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/) is a tool for that algorithm.

1. Rates choice A as a distance of 15.
2. Rates choice B as a distance of 6.
3. Rates choice C as a distance of 9.

EDIT: Sorry, I keep mixing strings in the levenshtein tool. Updated to correct answers.

Comment: Ok, I guess that is true.  I'll take a look at this.  I personally don't care *how* close it is to the target as long as it is pretty dang close.  No need for perfection ;)  Points for you until I can verify the results of your answer :)

Answer (score 20):

Lua implementation, for posterity:

```
function levenshtein_distance(str1, str2)
    local len1, len2 = #str1, #str2
    local char1, char2, distance = {}, {}, {}
    str1:gsub('.', function (c) table.insert(char1, c) end)
    str2:gsub('.', function (c) table.insert(char2, c) end)
    for i = 0, len1 do distance[i] = {} end
    for i = 0, len1 do distance[i][0] = i end
    for i = 0, len2 do distance[0][i] = i end
    for i = 1, len1 do
        for j = 1, len2 do
            distance[i][j] = math.min(
                distance[i-1][j  ] + 1,
                distance[i  ][j-1] + 1,
                distance[i-1][j-1] + (char1[i] == char2[j] and 0 or 1)
                )
        end
    end
    return distance[len1][len2]
end
```

Answer (score 17):

You might find this library helpful!
http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

It is currently available in Java, JavaScript, Dart, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python

It works pretty well too. I use it in a couple of my Lua projects.

And I don't think it would be too difficult to port it to other languages!

Answer (score 14):

You might be interested in this blog post.

http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python

Fuzzywuzzy is a Python library that provides easy distance measures such as Levenshtein distance for string matching. It is built on top of difflib in the standard library and will make use of the C implementation Python-levenshtein if available.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: For others reading this, Fuzzywuzzy actually implements a lot of the ideas in Alain's wonderful post.  If you're actually looking to use some of those ideas its a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in the context of a search engine or frontend against a database, you might consider using a tool like [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), with the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604) plugin.  This combination allows you to search against an index of strings with the results sorted by relevance, as determined by Levenshtein distance.

We've been using it against a large collection of artists and song titles when the incoming query may have one or more typos, and it's worked pretty well (and remarkably fast considering the collections are in the millions of strings).

Additionally, with Solr, you can search against the index on demand via JSON, so you won't have to reinvent the solution between the different languages you're looking at.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is hard to implement if the input data is too large (say millions of strings). I used elastic search to solve this.

Quick start : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/elasticsearch-net.html

Just insert all the input data into DB and you can search any string based on any edit distance quickly. Here is a C# snippet which will give you a list of results sorted by edit distance (smaller to higher)

```
var res = client.Search<ClassName>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
    .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.VariableName)
        .Query("SAMPLE QUERY")
        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(5))
    )
));
```

Comment: What library are you using? Some more information is needed for this to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A very, very good resource for these kinds of algorithms is Simmetrics: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

Unfortunately the awesome website containing a lot of the documentation is gone :(
In case it comes back up again, its previous address was this:
http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html

Voila (courtesy of "Wayback Machine"): http://web.archive.org/web/20081230184321/http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/simmetrics.html

You can study the code source, there are dozens of algorithms for these kinds of comparisons, each with a different trade-off. The implementations are in Java.

Answer (score 1):

To query a large set of text in efficient manner you can use the concept of Edit Distance/ Prefix Edit Distance.

> Edit Distance ED(x,y): minimal number of transfroms to get from term x to term y

But computing ED between each term and query text is resource and time intensive. Therefore instead of calculating ED for each term first we can extract possible matching terms using a technique called Qgram Index. and then apply ED calculation on those selected terms.

An advantage of Qgram index technique is it supports for Fuzzy Search.

One possible approach to adapt QGram index is build an Inverted Index using Qgrams. In there we store all the words which consists with particular Qgram, under that Qgram.(Instead of storing full string you can use unique ID for each string). You can use Tree Map data structure in Java for this.
Following is a small example on storing of terms

> col : **col**mbia, **col**ombo, gan**col**a, ta**col**ama

Then when querying, we calculate the number of common Qgrams between query text and available terms.

```
Example: x = HILLARY, y = HILARI(query term)
Qgrams
$$HILLARY$$ -> $$H, $HI, HIL, ILL, LLA, LAR, ARY, RY$, Y$$
$$HILARI$$ -> $$H, $HI, HIL, ILA, LAR, ARI, RI$, I$$
number of q-grams in common = 4
```

number of q-grams in common = 4.

For the terms with high number of common Qgrams, we calculate the ED/PED against the query term and then suggest the term to the end user.

you can find an implementation of this theory in following project(See "QGramIndex.java"). Feel free to ask any questions. https://github.com/Bhashitha-Gamage/City_Search

To study more about Edit Distance, Prefix Edit Distance Qgram index please watch the following video of Prof. Dr Hannah Bast https://www.youtube.com/embed/6pUg2wmGJRo (Lesson starts from 20:06)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can have a golang POC for calculate the distances between the given words. You can tune the `minDistance` and `difference` for other scopes.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NtrBzLdC3rE

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "strings"
)

var data string = `THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE GREEN CHICKEN-THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE RED COW-THE RED FOX JUMPED OVER THE BROWN COW`

const minDistance float64 = 2
const difference float64 = 1

type word struct {
    data    string
    letters map[rune]int
}

type words struct {
    words []word
}

// Print prettify the data present in word
func (w word) Print() {
    var (
        lenght int
        c      int
        i      int
        key    rune
    )
    fmt.Printf("Data: %s\n", w.data)
    lenght = len(w.letters) - 1
    c = 0
    for key, i = range w.letters {
        fmt.Printf("%s:%d", string(key), i)
        if c != lenght {
            fmt.Printf(" | ")
        }
        c++
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}

func (ws words) fuzzySearch(data string) ([]word, error) {
    var (
        w      word
        err    error
        founds []word
    )
    w, err = initWord(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Errors: %s\n", err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }
    // Iterating all the words
    for i := range ws.words {
        letters := ws.words[i].letters
        //
        var similar float64 = 0
        // Iterating the letters of the input data
        for key := range w.letters {
            if val, ok := letters[key]; ok {
                if math.Abs(float64(val-w.letters[key])) <= minDistance {
                    similar += float64(val)
                }
            }
        }

        lenSimilarity := math.Abs(similar - float64(len(data)-strings.Count(data, " ")))
        log.Printf("Comparing %s with %s i've found %f similar letter, with weight %f", data, ws.words[i].data, similar, lenSimilarity)
        if lenSimilarity <= difference {
            founds = append(founds, ws.words[i])
        }
    }

    if len(founds) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("no similar found for data: " + data)
    }

    return founds, nil
}

func initWords(data []string) []word {
    var (
        err   error
        words []word
        word  word
    )
    for i := range data {
        word, err = initWord(data[i])
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error in index [%d] for data: %s", i, data[i])
        } else {
            words = append(words, word)
        }
    }
    return words

}

func initWord(data string) (word, error) {
    var word word

    word.data = data
    word.letters = make(map[rune]int)
    for _, r := range data {
        if r != 32 { // avoid to save the whitespace
            word.letters[r]++
        }

    }
    return word, nil
}
func main() {
    var ws words
    words := initWords(strings.Split(data, "-"))
    for i := range words {
        words[i].Print()
    }
    ws.words = words

    solution, _ := ws.fuzzySearch("THE BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE RED COW")
    fmt.Println("Possible solutions: ", solution)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample using [C# is here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p2rXk6).

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World " + LevenshteinDistance("Hello","World"));
    Console.WriteLine("Choice A " + LevenshteinDistance("THE BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE RED COW","THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE GREEN CHICKEN"));
    Console.WriteLine("Choice B " + LevenshteinDistance("THE BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE RED COW","THE RED COW JUMPED OVER THE RED COW"));
    Console.WriteLine("Choice C " + LevenshteinDistance("THE BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE RED COW","THE RED FOX JUMPED OVER THE BROWN COW"));
}

public static float LevenshteinDistance(string a, string b)
{
    var rowLen = a.Length;
    var colLen = b.Length;
    var maxLen = Math.Max(rowLen, colLen);

    // Step 1
    if (rowLen == 0 || colLen == 0)
    {
        return maxLen;
    }

    /// Create the two vectors
    var v0 = new int[rowLen + 1];
    var v1 = new int[rowLen + 1];

    /// Step 2
    /// Initialize the first vector
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowLen; i++)
    {
        v0[i] = i;
    }

    // Step 3
    /// For each column
    for (var j = 1; j <= colLen; j++)
    {
        /// Set the 0'th element to the column number
        v1[0] = j;

        // Step 4
        /// For each row
        for (var i = 1; i <= rowLen; i++)
        {
            // Step 5
            var cost = (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 6
            /// Find minimum
            v1[i] = Math.Min(v0[i] + 1, Math.Min(v1[i - 1] + 1, v0[i - 1] + cost));
        }

        /// Swap the vectors
        var vTmp = v0;
        v0 = v1;
        v1 = vTmp;
    }

    // Step 7
    /// The vectors were swapped one last time at the end of the last loop,
    /// that is why the result is now in v0 rather than in v1
    return v0[rowLen];
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello World 4
Choice A 15
Choice B 6
Choice C 8
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more similarity measure which I once implemented in our system and was giving satisfactory results :-

**Use Case**

*There is a user query which needs to be matched against a set of documents.*

**Algorithm**

1. Extract keywords from the user query (relevant POS TAGS - Noun, Proper noun).
2. Now calculate score based on below formula for measuring similarity between user query and given document.

For every keyword extracted from user query :-

- Start searching the document for given word and for every subsequent occurrence of that word in the document decrease the rewarded points.

In essence, if first keyword appears 4 times in the document, the score will be calculated as :-

- first occurrence will fetch '1' point.
- Second occurrence will add 1/2 to calculated score
- Third occurrence would add 1/3 to total
- Fourth occurrence gets 1/4

Total similarity score = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 = 2.083

Similarly, we calculate it for other keywords in user query.

Finally, the total score will represent the extent of similarity between user query and given document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution that doesn't depend on any libraries, and works well enough for things like autocomplete forms:

```
function compare_strings(str1, str2) {
    arr1 = str1.split("");
    arr2 = str2.split("");
    res = arr1.reduce((a, c) => a + arr2.includes(c), 0);
    return(res)
}
```

Can use in an autocomplete input like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="tag_input" placeholder="add tags..."></input>
    <div id="hold_tags"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #2c2c54;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#wrapper {
  height: auto;
  background: #40407a;
}

.tag {
  background: #ffda79;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
const input = document.getElementById("tag_input");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const hold_tags = document.getElementById("hold_tags");
const words = [
  "machine",
  "data",
  "platform",
  "garbage",
  "twitter",
  "knowledge"
];
input.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  const value = document.getElementById(e.target.id).value;
  hold_tags.replaceChildren();
  if (value !== "") {
    words.forEach(function (word) {
      if (compare_strings(word, value) > value.length - 1) {
        const tag = document.createElement("div");
        tag.className = "tag";
        tag.innerText = word;
        hold_tags.append(tag);
      }
    });
  }
});

function compare_strings(str1, str2) {
  arr1 = str1.split("");
  arr2 = str2.split("");
  res = arr1.reduce((a, c) => a + arr2.includes(c), 0);
  return res;
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'boolean'.ts(2365)