# Is it possible to have a Search box on a form that searches through the labels

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to have a Search box on a form that searches through the labels in a panel with numerous tabs to then to go that label?

Comment: Yes it's absolutely possible. Iterate through the form child controls and check if it's a label then the rest goes to you.

Comment: you made that sound easy. An y chance of code example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you can search for the text in all the controls and then switch the selected Tab as below

```
 foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                var controls = tab.Controls; 
                foreach(Control c in controls)
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                    {
//depends if you want to search by label text or name 
                        string txt = c.Text;
                        string name = c.Name;

                        if (txt == textbox1.Text.Trim()) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: please mark as an answer if this answered your question

Comment: I would but i can't get it to work i don't even get an error

Comment: is there anyway of getting it to be more includes the text or like?

Comment: Instead of `txt == txtBox1.Text` ... use [_Fuzzy Text Matching_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218553/fuzzy-text-matching-c-sharp)

Comment: Use this  if(txt.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is there anyway of talking off case sensitive 
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            var controls = tab.Controls;
            foreach (Control c in controls)
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    //depends if you want to search by label text or name 
                    string txt = c.Text;
                    //string name = c.Name;
                    //MessageBox.Show(txt);
                    if (txt.Contains (textBox2.Text.Trim())) tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                    //MessageBox.Show(textBox2.Text.Trim());
                }
```

Comment: Use this  if(txt.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())