# SQL Server Partial Match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 columns that I am trying to see if there is a partial match between two strings. Column A has string: 0C000702AA-G and Column B has string S0C000702AB-DI. I did try:

```
CASE WHEN ColumnA LIKE '%' + ColumnB + '%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS 'Match'
```

but it returns a 0. Is there a better way to see if there is almost a match?

Column A = 0C000702AA-G and Column B = S0C000702AB-DI. As you can see Column B is almost the same as A, B has prefix of 'S' and ends with 'AB-DI'. The result should return 1 because the part in the middle '0C000702AA' is the same both sides.

I just tested:

```
CASE WHEN '%' + ColumnA + '%' LIKE '%' + ColumnB + '%' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS 'Match'
```

Still returns 0

Comment: That logic is never going to work, because ColumnA is not fully contained within ColumnB. In order to come up with a solution you need to be more exact about how much of the string in ColumnA needs to match part of ColumnB.

Comment: do you mean I should maybe try substring match? I think would work but the problem is that not all the codes are the same length.

Comment: I don't know what you should try until you can be more specific about your matching requirements. What exactly qualifies as a "partial match"?

Comment: @RuanduPreez, Gordon is right. as my answer does not directly answer your question, please un-accept my answer, so somebody might provide a better solution to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize DIFFERENCE function, which compares the SOUNDEX values of the two strings. If difference is 0, then no similarity. If the difference is 4, they are very similar. [Read more about SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2159/using-soundex-and-difference-to-standardize-data-in-sql-server/)

**CAVEAT:** The comparison is based on how the strings sound. So, it will not be very suitable for your needs, as you have got a identifier kind of thing, including digits.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(columnA CHAR(100), ColumnB CHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @table values 
('0C000702AA-G','S0C000702AB-DI')

SELECT SOUNDEX(ColumnA) as columnASoundex, SOUNDEX(columnB) as ColumnBSoundex, 
DIFFERENCE(ColumnA,ColumnB) as Similarity from @table
```

| columnASoundex | ColumnBSoundex | Similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000 | S000 | 3 |

But, if you want to go for even detailed comparison, you can use a CLR stored procedure leveraging C# fuzzy matching libraries like [fuzzystring](https://github.com/kdjones/fuzzystring). Also refer to SO post [fuzzy matching in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218553/fuzzy-text-matching-c-sharp#8218565)

**UPDATE** As OP confirmed, the above approach works only in some cases. So,  OP has to figure out a better approach, which would suit all his needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and some works well and others don't. There is places in my project where I can definitely use this function. Thanks

Comment: @RuanduPreez, in that case, you have go for detailed fuzzy matching, using CLR stored procedure to suit your needs using C# fuzzy matching.

Comment: @RuanduPreez, sure. If this answers your question, please mark it as answer, it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry. I thought that OP is going to use CLR approach using C# fuzzy logic to suit his needs and has accepted the answer. I agree with you. I will send message to OP to revert his decision.