# Match mismatched strings using c#

Tags: c#

I need to match two sets of strings that slightly differ from each other.

This is my data class:

```
public class AccountPair
{
    public string AccountNameA { get; set; }
    public string AccountNameB { get; set; }
    public int AccountNameB_ID {get; set;}
}
```

As a sample, AccountNameA is *John Doe Ltd* and AccountNameB is *John Doe (PTY) Limited*.

Using C#, I need to determine if AccountNameA is a match with AccountNameB and then output AccountNameA with the matched AccountNameB_ID.
Is there a way that this can be done because a simple string match won't work with these.

The output would be formatted as:

```
public class AccountPair
{
    public string AccountNameA { get; set; }
    public int AccountNameB_ID {get; set;}
}
```

***UPDATE***

Some Clarification from my side, We have a CRM systems where the companies get created when a client signs up with us. After this, an employee will log onto our Web Application and recreate the Account there. Now when the CRM account gets created, a simple Company Trading name is used, but when the company gets created on our Web Application, the full company registered name is used, thus there is a difference in the company name between the two systems.
I need to match the CRM company names with the WebApp company names and then store the WebApp CompanyID to the CRM Company profile so we can build further integrations between the CRM and the WebApp.

Comment: What have you tried? What rules are making a different string equal?

Comment: You need to give more information about how you think you could match the names.

Comment: Some Clarification from my side, We have a CRM systems where the companies get created when a client signs up with us. After this, an employee will log onto our Web Application and recreate the Account there. Now when the CRM account gets created, a simple Company Trading name is used, but when the company gets created on our Web Application, the full company registered name is used, thus there is a difference in the company name between the two systems.

Comment: I need to match the CRM company names with the WebApp company names and then store the WebApp CompanyID to the CRM Company profile so we can build further integrations between the CRM and the WebApp.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add these extra details. It makes it so much easier to read and understand what you're asking?

Comment: @Hennericho: Would it be feasible to build a dictionary for the mapping between both systems? That would be the most efficient way. And if there is a new you could log this and fallback to simple string comparison.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this would be a solution, the problem is that there is 28k companies on our WebApp and to build a Dictionary manually is very time consuming thus we would like to programmatically do this for us.

Comment: @Hennericho: You can easily create the code to build the dictionary programatically. But that is a different question than what you have asked and we don't have enough information to help you with that task.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Isn't that a catch-22 type situation? That's what the OP asking for, right?

Comment: How many data entries are we talking here? It looks like you're doing a cartesian product, which is not optimal, but might be ok depending on the size of the input set. Generally you'll have to do fuzzy matching, e.g. with the Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70201387), where they suggested to use a 3rd party library for it:

> Please have a look at https://github.com/JakeBayer/FuzzySharp

You can do something like the following with the 3rd party NuGet package mentioned in the answer above:

```
if (Fuzz.Ratio(accountPair.AccountNameA, accountPair.AccountNameB) > 90)
{
   // You found a possible match.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var acc = new AccountPair() {
    AccountNameA = "John Doe Ltd",
    AccountNameB = "John Doe (PTY)",
    AccountNameB_ID = 1
};

Pair? pair = acc?.FindPair();

public class AccountPair
{
    public string AccountNameA { get; set; }
    public string AccountNameB { get; set; }
    public int AccountNameB_ID { get; set; }


    public Pair? FindPair()
    {
        List<string> words = new();

        foreach (var word in this.AccountNameA.Split(" "))
        {
            if (this.AccountNameB.Contains(word))
            {
                words.Add(word);
            }
        }

        string name = String.Join(" ", words);

        if(this.AccountNameA.Contains(name))
        {
            return new Pair { AccountNameA = this.AccountNameA, AccountNameB_ID = this.AccountNameB_ID };
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Pair
{
    public string AccountNameA { get; set; }
    public int AccountNameB_ID { get; set; }
}
```