# Basic search functionality with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, search

I'm looking for a basic search functionality with JavaScript.

**The Scenario**: The user enters a single or multiple words, and hit a button. JavaScript looks up in an array of strings for items that probably relates to the entered search sentence.

The only function I'm aware of right now is "string.search" which returns the position of the string you are searching for. This is good, but not for all cases. Here are a few examples the search function should cover

Let's assume I have the following string: "This is a good day" in my array. The following search terms should return true when tested against my search function.

- Search Term 1: This a good day
- Search Term 2: This day
- Search Term 3: This was good
- Search Term 4: good dy -*the user made a typo*-

So nothing particular or specific. Just a basic search functionality that predicts (at a low level, and language agnostic) if the search term related to the strings in the tested array.

Comment: You mean something like that: http://nakajima.github.com/jquery-livesearch/

Comment: Lots and lots of programming. Your "This was good" and "good dy" examples, and to a lesser degree "This day", are non-trivial.

Comment: You may try searching for "javascript live search"

Comment: @Nupul Could you read the full question. That search plugin is even case sensitive.

Comment: Why not ask Google to lend you their semantic search algorithm? `:)`

Comment: @Amadan Yes, I'm aware of that. That's why I didn't venture to build my own script from the first while and thought about asking the community. I did some Google searches but I found nothing

Comment: @AbidOmar - I asked something *like* the link...not sure if that's what you were looking for and hence the comment. Putting a '?' at the end of the URL would break it

Comment: @Sebas The case when user made a typo in their search term.

Comment: @Nupul: Off topic, but a common fix to that is to leave a space, even if not typographically correct. http://example.com/ ?

Comment: @AbidOmar - Yes I thought of that :) Anyways - for the sake of completeness and I can't edit my comment here's is probably something that you are looking for that will take in typos as well as any 'sequential' pattern that you specify - http://ejohn.org/apps/livesearch/

Comment: So, you want to compensate for user typos (#4) and semantic verb times (#3)? I like how the title is "**Basic** search functionality" and you didn't even show any code in the question. Seriously, your best bet is going with Evert's answer (maybe using OR'ed instead of AND'ed and ordering results by relevance).

Comment: @Nupul The script you mentioned satisfies my search criteria. You can post it as answer and I'll accept i.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Maybe we have different definition of "basic":). I'd think of taking language, history and other things into account as an advanced thing.

Comment: I see. @Nupul's recommended plugin fits between our definitions of basic very well, also.

Comment: @AbidOmar - your wish is my command :P Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is a pattern matching based *live search* similar to finite-state-automata-like (FSA) searching:

[This link shows an example](http://ejohn.org/apps/livesearch) that'll allow you to search case-insensitively:

Example: Array contains 'This is a good day'

Searching for any (or all) of the following is valid:

- THis a Day
- Thagd (**Th** is **a**  **g** oo **d** day)
- good dy *-intended typo-*

etc.

A case-sensitive (albeit not perfect FSA based) version can be found [here](http://nakajima.github.com/jquery-livesearch) There is also [one by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/) but I don't have a link to his demo but it'd be worth looking at - it's a javascript/jquery port of the first link I mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Was the last a typo for 'day'?

If not, you could simply split the search sentence, as well as the original string using the split() function.

Then you would iterate over the search words and for each make sure they appear in the source string. As soon as you don't find the word, you stop the search.

This is assuming that all the search words should be AND'ed, not OR'ed.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple as one would think. We're talking fuzzy matching and Levenshtein distance / algorithm.

See this past question: 
[Getting the closest string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match)