# Highlighting text differences between 2 Java Strings

Tags: java, string

I would like to highlight and report out text differences between 2 Strings with Java . What is a good way to do this? Do I need to tokenize both Strings and do a compare or is there an easier way?

Example:

I have 2 Strings like so:

Previous String  : CLIMB TO 5900' then climbing RIGHT turn to 11000' on heading 193 and outbound
Current String : CLIMB TO 6500' then climbing LEFT turn to 11000'on heading 201 and inbound

I am currently just displaying the previous and current strings by doing a String compare, but what i want is to highlight the actual substring that did change from the previous string, like so:

Current String : CLIMB TO **6500'** then climbing **LEFT** turn to 11000'on heading **201** and **inbound**

Appreciate your help!

Thank you
praveen

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303631/what-are-some-algorithms-for-comparing-how-similar-two-strings-are

Answer (score -1):

Yes , you can possibly tokenize the string characters . Use **charAt**(int index) to tokenize the string characters. You can see the example code below : -

```
for(int i=0 ; i<stringNameOrg.length ; i++)
{
   if(stringNameOrg.charAt(i) != stringNameNew.charAt(i))) //considering both strings are of same size
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely wrong... What if the length of the strings not matching... For Example "LEFT 2010" and "RIGHT 2010".

Comment: You are right . But I have already written that "considering both strings are of same size". I haven't given proper code . It's just an example

Comment: But that is not the answer for the question asked.

Comment: Ok friend, i got your point.  But we shouldn't spoonfeed people. Basically we should just give an idea to them

Comment: Yes, that is correct. there could be instances where the length of the Strings may not match. That was just an example I presented to the forum.

Comment: Would the diffutils from Google serve my need here? Thanks

Comment: Yes , you can try that too. Another thing you can do is extract each word from the two strings and compare them.!!!