# Same strings optimization

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Yesterday I had a question about an algorithm to check if two strings are the same. I wrote it:

```
var isSame = function(a, b) {
  if (a.length !== b.length) return false;

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

But after, an interviewer asked me to optimize it. I didn't it because I don't understand how I can do it. I forgot to ask interview about the answer because the interviewer left chat so fast. Now, I also can't find on the internet how to do it. That is possible?

Comment: Is this JavaScript? Please add a language tag. Also what's wrong with `return a === b`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15303672/3541845). A similar question was answered before.

Comment: @TagirValeev: clearly by using library builtins, you do not show much inslight into algorithms

Comment: Optimize in what sense? For performance? Readability? Maintenance?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, then the question should specify explicitly what is allowed to use. Why `.length` and `[i]` can be used? Is something else can be used as well?

Comment: Yes, we used JavaScript! Updated answer

Comment: If you want to optimize to make it not blow up, first check `a` and `b` are not null or undefined

Comment: @BobNapkin: an optimization I can think of is reference equality since in most languages string constructs use some kind of flyweight pattern. But I don't know the details how to check reference equality of strings in JavaScript.

Comment: I think @Codor has asked the million dollar question there! If it's for performance, just Google the strcmp algorhythm. If it's for maintenance, put some comments and better variable names in there!

Comment: @h2ooooooo yep. `function isSame(a,b){ return a===b;}` <- super optimized

Comment: @Codor he asked: 'can I do it faster?'

Comment: @BobNapkin Complexity-wise, without any additional assumptions, it cannot be done faster than `O(n)` where `n` is the sum of the lengths of both strings, as the result depends on each bit of the input.

Comment: @BenHillier thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty canonical to me. You just check for whether the lengths are different and then check each letter.

If there's a hash function, you could just compare the two. But either way it doesn't save you from touching every bit of each string.

Comment: Actionally you do not need to touch every bit of each string, and OP does not do it either. As soon as you find a difference, you can stop and do not have to check the rest of the strings.

Comment: In the worst case, you will find the strings differ on only the last bit.

Comment: @Ridcully: but that's the case here because of the `return false` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly. As I said, the OP does **not** touch every bit of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Well `strA === strB` should be sufficient for strings.

Or use ES2015's `Object.is` (which is overkill for strings, I'd say)

```
Object.is('foo', 'bar') //=> false
Object.is('Bar', 'Bar') //=> true
```

Comment: Does this also work for that? `var a = 'Bar'; var b = 'Bar'; var equal = Object.is(a, b);` ?

Comment: Sure, it does, just try it in your browser developer console.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you'd obviously just compare that strings. But if you ask yourself how you could improve from an **algorithmic** point of view, let me say that what you do is the most performant way to compare two strings (at least I think so, I didn't prove it).
From an **implementation** point of view, you could test if [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) helps you speed up the code.

With loop unrolling you basically copy and paste your code in the loop body. This way you have less comparisons (jumps). Use it like this:

```
var isSame = function(a, b) {
   if (a.length !== b.length) return false;

   var unrollFactor = 5; // This is where you can play around to find better solutions
   var i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < a.length - unrollFactor; i += unrollFactor) {
      if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
      if (a[i+1] !== b[i+1]) return false;
      if (a[i+2] !== b[i+2]) return false;
      if (a[i+3] !== b[i+3]) return false;
      if (a[i+4] !== b[i+4]) return false;
   }

   // If there is a rest, compare it:
   for (i = i-unrollFactor; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }

   return true;
}
```

This is just theoretical. In practice I doubt you'd ever really need this in javascript :)