# How to count/measure correlation of text in excel?

Tags: excel, correlation

I know we can measure the "sameness" in signal using cross-corellation, but how do we calculate the percentage of "sameness" in text?

for example we have:
1. "The Legend of Awesome Dog"
2. "Dog Awesome The legend of"
which is like 100% same but shuffled.

but when paired with :
3. "Dog awesome number 9" which only got 40% sameness with sentence 1 or 2.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303672/8112776).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [aproximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). There is a free [add-on](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011) for Excel, developed by Microsoft to create a so called Fuzzy match. It uses the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) algorithm to determine the similarity of two given values.

- Make sure that both columns are a table (Ctrl+L);
- Link the columns in the 'Left Columns' and the 'Right Columns' section and press the connect button in the middle;
- Select which columns you want as output (hold Ctrl if you want to select multiple columns on either the left or the right side);
- Make sure the `FuzzyLookup.Similarity` is checked;
- Determine the maximum number of matches shown per comparable string;
- Determine your Threshold. The number represents the minimum percentage of similarity between two strings before it marks it as a match;
- Go to a new sheet to cell A1;
- Hit the 'Go'button!
- Select all the similarity scores and give them more decimals for a proper result.

[See example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgSrF.png)