# How to know the common characters in two Strings dart

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart

I want to compare two Strings either they contain similar characters to print the number of common characters

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the common characters between two strings you can use the below method,

```
void findCommonCharacters(){
    var str="geeksforgeeks";
    var str2="platformforgeeks";

    Set<String> uniqueList={};
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
      if(str2.contains(str[i])){
        uniqueList.add(str[i]);
        print("val : ${str[i]}");
      }
    }
  }
```

This will give you the common characters between the two strings.

> Also, to match characters of one String with another you can use default methods of String like contains(), startswith() and endswith() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match strings have a look at the Levenshtein Distance:

[What are some algorithms for comparing how similar two strings are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303631/what-are-some-algorithms-for-comparing-how-similar-two-strings-are)