# Match Strings with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(kword == term){
    $(this).trigger('click');
}
```

The case is if the `kword` is "car" and the `term` is "cars", I would want that to be a positive match.
Currently I'm looking at an exact match. As I'm a novice at jquery I don't know how to do this. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: what's the problem? the code above looks ok

Comment: @Ekansh Rastogi The strings don't need to match, but the string should contain the other

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the string inside another

```
if(term.indexOf(kword)>-1){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply compare a string variable with a different string variable with an 's' in the end, you can go with following code:

```
if (term === kword + 's') {
    ...
}
```

If you need to check specifically if terms is a plural version of kword, you would need much larger implementation, featuring `pluralize` function (that you need to implement or search for a library):

```
if (term === pluralize(kword)) {
    ...
}

function pluralize(word) {
   //implement function
}
```

If that doesn't not answer your question, please be more clear about what you need to do.

Comment: No i wasn't referring to plurals, i was looking for closest match situations. User may input something like "care" and the closest match could be careless, does that make more sense?

Comment: Okay, that is way more complicated then. You need a algorythm, like [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match) to see how. You can't use jQuery API to do that (jQuery is about traversing HTML elements, listening to input, making AJAX requests etc.). If you want a simpler implementation, please be VERY specific on how you want it to work in as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anton said, you can use indexOf(), it returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string otherwise returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs. Also note that this method is case sensitive.