# Excel formula, find similar string between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want find a formula who allows to check like this :

column 1 :
row 1 : "AAA AA ABB A"
...

column 2 :
row 1 : "LLL BBLL"
...

the formula return TRUE with rows 1 of the two columns because there is "BB"
I don't want search "BB" but find if two rows are "similare" like this example.
Thanks you =)

Is it possible via formula ? (no vb)

Comment: You need a strict definition on what "similar" is.  Otherwise, we have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I think you need fuzzy matching - see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/437387/comparing-similar-text-strings-in-excel) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match)...

Comment: @Yaegz : "You need a strict definition on what "similar" is " , you are right, i'm sorry. I need to know if any substring in a row in the column one is somewhere in the other column (no need to know the number of the row, just if its true or false). Is that clear?

Comment: @zx8754 : I am boring I know :) but I'm looking for a solution without vb and new installation, just know if is possible with the "basic" formula

Comment: Would you consider a match, if it was one B?

Comment: Damn I see, you make a point...If I want check the sub chain with a minimal number of characters (4 for example) ? but the problem begin (too) complex for formula ?

Comment: if you only wanted 1 length of substring to match, it could be done, but excel doesn't want to play with 2 arrays for `MID(`.  vba will probably be your only choice

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe possible with the following approach:

[image]

This is a German Excel. WAHR=TRUE and FALSCH=FALSE ;-)

Formulas in 
C4:

`{=NOT(AND(ISERROR(FIND(MID($A4,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A4)-$C$2+1)),$C$2),$B4))))}`

and in D4:

`{=NOT(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID($A4,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN($A4)-$C$2+1)),$C$2),$B4))))}`

These are array formulas. Input them in the cell without the curly brackets and the press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to complete.

The approach is to get an array of $C$2 length substings from string in column A and find/search them in the string in column B.