# JS find better string match

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have three strings:

```
var s1 = 'Tokyo';
var s2 = 'Tokyo is pretty neat';
var s3 = 'Tokyo is pretty neat at summer';
```

And I wanna compare `s3` to `s2` and `s1`  and find the 'best' match for `s3` among `s1` and `s2`. I mean, the matching algorithm should return `s2` in this case, as it has more in common with `s3`. How can I do that? As a rule, simple check using indexOf() was enough for me, but now I need to find the 'best' match.

Comment: List matches and then take the longest one ?

Comment: You probably need to clarify what best match means.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match

Comment: @DTing Sure. Best match means strings start with the same substring and it's length is maximal among all possible matches

Comment: So, `Tokyo is pretty neat at summertime` would never be a match?

Comment: @Xotic750 It would. As it contains the whole string, whose match we are loking for

Comment: And what would be a closer match with something like `Tokyo is pretty neat at summer start` and `Tokyo is pretty neat at summer break`?

Comment: Indifferent. A solution that would work only for matching a string with shorter strings would be fine actually

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

Basically, it takes two strings and finds the difference between them. 
If the distance between the two strings are small it means that the strings are more similar to each other.

Let's take your example

Query: Tokyo is pretty neat at summer

S2: Tokyo is pretty neat = 10

S3: Tokyo = 25

[Online Demo of the algorithm](http://planetcalc.com/1721/)

[Here is a javascript library](https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments, this example should suffice.

```js
var tests = [
    'Tokyo',
    'Tokyo is pretty neat'
    ],
    actual = 'Tokyo is pretty neat at summer';

var firstClosest = tests.reduce(function (acc, test) {
    if (test === actual.slice(0, test.length) && test.length > acc.length) {
        acc = test;
    }
    
    return acc;
}, '');

document.getElementById('out').textContent = firstClosest;
```

```html
<pre id='out'></pre>
```