# Find substring in text which has the highest similarity to a given keyword

Tags: text, machine-learning, data-mining, string-algorithm

Say I have this text = `I love apples, kiwis, oranges and bananas` and the searchString = `kiwis and bananas` and [a similarity algorithm](https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity) say [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). How can I efficiently find the substring in `text` which has the highest similarity to `searchString`.

Basically I am trying to find portions of text (text has high errors, misspellings, extra symbols and spaces) which match a list of keywords I have.

Comment: i dont know much about this but this link might help ...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @Dandy: I know about edit distance. This question is asking given strings S and T, find a substring of S that has the smallest edit distance (or any other similarity metric) to T.

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf

Comment: @Dandy: Thanks for the link but I know the min edit distance problem. Not sure how it applied to my question? Can you provide an answer below detailing what you are trying to say?

Comment: did you got your solution

Answer (score 5):

Jaccard index is "lucky" similarity algorithm, because you can update it's value for new symbol without recalculating all previous stuff. So, you can view `text` as a sequence of diffs for resulting index value. After that, problem can be reduced to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem.

What about your second paragraph, if you are doing some NLP-like research, I'd suggest to clean your data (remove those extra symbols and spaces, whenever that's possible) before further processing. That's known as "spelling correction", and there are tons of different algorithms and libraries. To choose appropriate one, extra information about your domain is needed.

Comment: > Jaccard index is "lucky" similarity algorithm, because you can update it's value for new symbol without recalculating all previous stuff.

Can you explain or provide a link regarding what you mean above?

Comment: Assume sets are `A = {1, 2, 3}` and `B = {1}`, JI is `1/3`. If you add new value to `B`,  you can simply update numerator and denominator -- `B += {2}`, JI becomes `(1 + 1) / (3 + 0) = 2/3`, values `1` and `0` can be calculated without rest of `B`. As long as we work with sets, `contains` operation is pretty efficient. (This example can be easily extended to strings)

Comment: (For previous comment -- to check if, for example, `1` already was calculated in numerator, we need additional check, that can be done in amortized constant time too (however, required max space is space of `A`). Actually interesting question -- what would be more efficient, to find diffs for `searchString` and check `contains` for `text`, or visa verse. I bet that doesn't matter, and going to write proof.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at shingling technique, and try to find the similarity.
you can follow this link: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html

For example use 9 shingle and compare each subset with your specific keyword

Comment: I believe the algorithm I am using (Jacard index) is based on k-shingling anyway

Answer (score 1):

I Use [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)
and [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

This is the algorithm in action: https://wizsearch.wizsoft.com/index.php/demo/

This demo searches all wiki titles, try the "show search terms" option to see the Levenshtein distance and error correction algorithm in action.

Answer (score 0):

Every query term is checked against a dictionary.
If a term is not found in the dictionary, then those words from the dictionary are shown as spelling suggestions, which are most similar to the query term in question.

**Similarity / Edit distance**
As similarity measure between two words serves usually the Damerau-Levenshtein distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Few other references

- http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/
- http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/07/improved-edit-distance-based-spelling-correction/