# Best match of a string from a predefined list of values?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, match, spreadsheet

I am doing a survey on household appliances, visiting stores. I note down the full model number by hand in a notebook. Back home, I need to fill these in a spreadsheet. I have a partial list of the model numbers. I want to minimise my effort by entering only unique parts of the model number string.

1. I'm using vlookup with * wildcard in excel for non-exact match. But problem is that it returns the first match, even though a better match is available.
2. Also, I might miss out on a hyphen or "/" and I need some mechanism to correct for that.

Is there any solution for Excel, Libreoffice/Openoffice or Google Sheets?

Comment: Any clues anyone? I need help urgently..

Comment: Can you share the code and a sample with dummy data? It is easier to correct than to make up something new, not to mention it will show what you've done so far.

Comment: Sample models in database: RT28K3043S8/NL, RT28K3083S9/NL, GL-Q/282SGSM, GL-B/282SGSM;   sample entry in cell: b282sg, formula in cell=VLOOKUP("*"&B2&"*",$A$2:$B$485,1,TRUE) ;; might return cell GL-Q/282SGSM, which is a lesser match than GL-B/282SGSM. I'd want it to be the latter, obviously. I want to save time by entering only the unique part of each product code string

Comment: Even it might sound easy, but finding closest match with strings is harder than it seems. Check [Getting the closest string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match)

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model numbers are in column A and your search value is in B2, you can use this. It will handle the "/".

```
=query(A:A,"select A where lower(A) contains '"& lower(B2) &"'")
```