# VBA - Returning values from a table which fit a certain criteria and outputting them in a new sheet

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-2013

**Background:**

As part of a project I am working on which involves [fuzzy string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), I have implemented the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm in VBA to calculate the "similarity" between two strings (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914499/fuzzy-string-matching-optimization-not-checking-certain-words-excel-vba-func) for part of the code/more insight into my project).

So, I created a table in `Sheet1` in Excel with row and column headers which are strings (located in cells `A2:A2146` and `B1:TU1`, respectively), and I am comparing these strings with the `LevenshteinDistance` function. The function populates the empty cells in the table (in my case, `B2:TU2146`) with what I call the `matchScore`. The idea is this: the more similar two strings are, the lower their `matchScore`. It follows that if two strings match exactly, we would have `matchScore = 0`.

(1) More specifically, suppose the value of `S1` (one of my column headers) is "recursion" and the value of cell `A532`(one of my row headers) is "recursion". After executing my "similarity" function, the value returned in cell `S532` of the table is `0`.

**What I want to achieve:**

For the purposes of my problem and the heuristic I've defined to measure string similarity, I am particularly interested in string pairs for which `matchScore <= 1` is true (this includes the example (1) above).

The data table is huge, and it is difficult for me to get visibility into the "good data" (`matchScore <= 1`). **Thus, I want Excel to find each value in the table which is <=1 and output them in** `Sheet2` **along with the strings that were paired off as "good matches."** Therefore, there should be three columns of data in `Sheet2`. To reference again the example above (1), when my code finishes running, I should see `0`, "recursion", and "recursion" in cells `A1` through `C1` (assuming this was the only "good match" I found in the table).

**What I have tried to implement as a solution:**

```
Sub FindMatches()

Dim r As Long, c As Range
r = 1

For Each c In Range("B2:BY2146").Cells
    If c.Value <= 1 Then Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(c.Value, Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(1, c.Column))
    r = r + 1
Next c

End Sub
```

Effectively, this sub does nothing. Where am I wrong in the way I am attempting to implement my solution, and what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Any reason you don't simply sort ascending on the result, so that the strongest matches float to the top, and the weakest to the bottom?

Comment: @jeffreyweir doing that wouldn't necessarily improve my visibility into the data just by nature of the strings I'm comparing, but it could be useful in the future! Is there a way I can build that into my sub? I have tried to do this here:

`Sub Sort_Data_Ascending()

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:C").Sort _
Key1:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") _
Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub`

But I have a syntax error somewhere. Any help? Am new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated sub:

```
Sub FindMatches()
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim r As Long, c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        r = 1
        For Each c In Range("B2:BY2146").Cells
            If c.Value <= 1 Then
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(c.Value, Cells(c.Row, 1).Value, Cells(1, c.Column).Value)
                r = r + 1
            End If                
        Next c
    End With

Recover:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Recover
End Sub
```

Note that `Array` returns a one-dimensional array, whereas `.Value`, when assigned an array, expects a 2D one. So I've split the assignments across 3 lines of code.

**EDIT**
To my surprise, assigning a 1D, zero-based array to the .Value property of a single-row range works beautifully, whereas I thought a 2D, 1-based was a requirement. So my initial paragraph above is baloney and @Profex really found the issue.

A `With` block provides a bit more performance, and the `Application.ScreenUpdating` management provides lots more. It is important to reset `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `True` in case of error.

Beware of unqualified references, i.e. `Range` and `Cells` not preceded by their parent object (e.g. `... In Range("B2:BY2146").Cells` and `Cells(c.Row, 1)`; those are looking at whichever worksheet is the active one when they're invoked. In your case, if the source values are on Sheet1, you could use e.g. `... In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:BY2146").Cells` and `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, 1)`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `r = r + 1` be in the `If` block, so that they're not randomly on `sheet2`

Answer (score 0):

Qualify sheets("sheet1") in the assignment statement & loop.
Put r=r+1 inside the if statement.

```
Sub FindMatches()

Dim r As Long, c As Range
r = 1

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:BY2146").Cells
If c.Value <= 1 Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 3)).Value = Array(c.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Cells(c.Row, 1), Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, c.Column).Value)
    r = r + 1
End If
Next c
End Sub
```