# Minhashing on Strings with K-length

Tags: probability, bloom-filter, minhash

I have a application where I should implement Bloom Filters and Minhashing to find similar items.

I have the Bloom Filter implemented but I need to make sure i understand the Minhashing part to do it:

- The aplication generates a number of k-length Strings and stores it in a document, then all of those are inserted in the Bloom.
- Where I want to implement the MinHash is by giving the option for the user to insert a String and then compare it and try to find the most similar ones on the document.

Do i have to Shingle all the Strings on the document? The problem is that I can't really find something to help me in theis, all I find is regarding two documents and never one String to a set of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

So: the user enters a string and the application finds the most similar strings within a single document. By "similarity", do you mean something like Levenstein distance (whereby "cat" is deemed similar to "rat" and "cart"), or some other measure? And are you (roughly speaking) looking for similar paragraphs, similar sentences, similar phrases or similar words? These are important considerations.

Also, you say you are comparing one string to a set of strings. What are these strings? Sentences? Paragraphs? If you are sure you don't want to find any similarities spanning multiple paragraphs (or multiple sentences, or what-have-you) then it makes sense to think of the document as multiple separate strings; otherwise, you should think of it as a single long string.

The MinHash algorithm is for comparing many documents to each other, when it's impossible to store all document in memory simultaneously, and individually comparing every document to every other would be an n-squared problem. MinHash overcomes these problems by storing hashes for only some shingles, and it sacrifices some accuracy as a result. You don't need MinHash, as you could simply store every shingle in memory, using, say, 4-character-grams for your shingles. But if you don't expect word orderings to be switched around, you may find the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) more suitable (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match)).

If you're expecting the user to enter long strings of words, you may get better results basing your shingles on words; so 3-word-grams, for instance, ignoring differences in whitespacing, case and punctuation.

Generating 4-character-grams is simple: "The cat sat on the mat" would yield "The ", "he c", "e ca", " cat", etc. Each of these would be stored in memory, along with the paragraph number it appeared in. When the user enters a search string, that would be shingled in identical manner, and the paragraphs containing the greatest number of shared shingles can be retrieved. For efficiency of comparison, rather than storing the shingles as strings, you can store them as hashes using FNV1a or a similar cheap hash.

Shingles can also be built up from words rather than characters (e.g. "the cat sat", "cat sat on", "sat on the"). This tends to be better with larger pieces of text: say, 30 words or more. I would typically ignore all differences in whitespace, case and punctuation if taking this approach.

If you want to find matches that can span paragraphs as well, it becomes quite a bit more complex, as you have to store the character positions for every shingle and consider many different configurations of possible matches, penalizing them according to how widely scattered their shingles are. That could end up quite complex code, and I would seriously consider just sticking with a Levenstein-based solution such as Smith-Waterman, even if it doesn't deal well with inversions of word order.

I don't think a bloom filter is likely to help you much, though I'm not sure how you're using it. Bloom filters *might* be useful if your document is highly structured: a limited set of possible strings and you're searching for the existence of one of them. For natural language, though, I doubt it will be very useful.