# Spanish mark do not correspond with displaying in EXCEL

Tags: excel, string, vlookup

I want match the data via "Vlookup"

But in spanish case,
There is a match error casue a little bit  in contents name.

I want match the name "BegoñaOlavide" via "vlookup"
But although there are same keyword in displaying,
One some have a 'Begon­´aOlavide' data, so that mismatched

how can I handle with that's discordant keyword to same word contents

[image]

[image]

And i attatch more case,
There are same in display, but
when i select the colomn, one is transfered another mark the third sample.

I don't know why each same display mark have a diffrent word,
and don't know when The one was changed exaclty,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the data coming from for column D?  Can you fix the source there so it shows the correct character?  If not, perhaps you could modify your `VLOOKUP` to replace the problem character (assuming it's the only one)  Try something like: `=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"ñ","­´"),...`  If that doesn't help, or there is more than the one character, please share more sample data as well as the formula you're using so far.  (See "[mcve]"  and also [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) for more tips about asking questions.)

Comment: i attached more case, thank you.

Comment: As per @Ashleedawg's. Also, depending on the number of cases, simply add these different spellings to your mapping table and map them to the same item. Not ideal if large numbers of different possible spellings - you might then be thinking about fuzzy matching.

Comment: There is an [add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15011) available, which I have never tried.  No idea if that works for different languages or if you can customize. There is also at least one excellent [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match) on fuzzy matching by someone who was working on an oil rig

Comment: I just found a **[*¡fórmula horrenda!* on this page](http://howtouseexcel.net/excel-formula-to-change-foreign-accented-characters-to-regular-non-accented-characters)** that I wouldn't recommend, but *just had to* share, lol. **I'll paste as much as I can fit**, haha: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUT…`

Comment: `…E(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")",""),"á","a"),"é","e"),"í","i"),"ó","o"),"ú","u"),"ã","a"),"ê","e"),"â","a"),"é","e")…`

Comment: `…,"è","e"),"î","i"),"ï","i"),"ç","c"),"ä","a"),"ö","o"),"ü","u"),"ß","ss"),"ş","s"),"ı","i"),"ğ","g"),"ę","e"),"ł","l"),"ń","n"),"ś","s"),"ż","z"),"ã","a"),"ầ","a"),"à","a"),"ậ","a"),"đ","d"),"ế","e"),"ì","i"),"í","i"),"ổ","o"),"ô","o"),"ư","u"),"ả","a"),"ế","e"),"ĩ","i"),"ợ","o"),"ồ","o"),"ạ","a"),"ứ","u"),"ý","y"),"ạ","a"),"é","e"),"ỳ","y"),"ế","e"),"ể","e"),"ệ","e"),"ù","u"),"ë","e"),".",""),"Ġ","g"),"ø","o"),"ñ","n"),"'",""),"ō","o"),"--","-"),"ħ","h"),"å","a"),"æ","ae"),"Ġ","g"),"Č","c"),"ě","e"),"ň","n"),"š","s"),"ě","e"),"ň","n"),"ž","z"),"ř","r"),"č","c"),"ġ","g")` Haha **sorry**

Comment: *ANYHOW*, yeah if your list of possible letters is more reasonable (perhaps `á é í ó ú ü ñ ¿ ¡ `?) ,then you could use the same idea, except changing to `"­´"`...