# Creating % match between inputted sequence and sequence stored in database (questionnaire) PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, match

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

A customer completes an assessment, each answer is a radio value between 1-5 and there are 10 questions. So therefore;

***Assessment Table***

assessmentid | studentid | q1 | q2 | q3.....q10

1      - 1001   -  1    - 5   - 3    -  2

The careers table has 10 careers which are each rated between 1-5 (this is set for each career)

***Careers Table***

careerid | careername | q1 | q2 | q3.....q10

1        -   Doctor   -   5  -  2  -  1   -  3

Im trying to create a results page which will check one sequence against another such as q1 in the assessment table against q1 in the careers table.

To explain further, the user will input a value between 1-5 for question 1. This will be matched for the q1 value for career1. This will be repeated for each question up until question 10. The overall result (% match) will be displayed - i.e. the %match for the user and that particular career. This process will then be repeated for all remaining careers.

I want the results to be shown in descending order and only display the top 5.

The results should be shown as

Career Name (result % match)
Hyperlink (to external website)

At the minute I have it working but it has quite a lot of queries such as:

```
<?php
$career1sequence1 = mysql_result (mysql_query ("SELECT `q1` FROM `careers` WHERE `careerid ` = '1'"), 0):
$question1 = mysql_result (mysql_query ("SELECT `q1` FROM `assessment` WHERE `studentid` = $session_studentid"), 0);
$career1result1 = $question1/$career1sequence1;
if ($career1result1>1)  {
    $career1result1 = $careersequence1/$question1
}
?>
```

This query is repeated for every question input/career sequence value. 
Would anyone know if there is an easier way to do this that is more straightforward?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have got a application in which we would like to verify entered names by the user in a Web application and to check real time against a huge database of names. If any matched names is found, it has to be reported. I had seen your output result ( [Fuzzy text (sentences/titles) matching in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480/fuzzy-text-sentences-titles-matching-in-c-sharp?rq=1) ) which is almost similar to what we require. We are using a MS SQL Database and and use Levenshtein logic and the matching %. It currently takes almost 2 minutes for a transaction when executed. Hope to assist me in optimizing / tuning them. Thanks