# Tool or API needed to find text contain any word from a large dictionary of words

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search

I'm looking for a tool (ideally) or failing that an API to search text for instances of any word from a large dictionary of words in a large number of text files. "Words" in my case are actually file names but won't contain spaces.

A fast algorithm might perhaps build a DFA (deterministic finite automata) by reading the dictionary and then be able to use a single pass to find instances of the dictionary words over any number of files.

**Note**: I'm wanting exact text matching not fuzzy matching like this SO question: 
 - [Algorithm wanted: Find all words of a dictionary that are similar to words in a free text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661434/algorithm-wanted-find-all-words-of-a-dictionary-that-are-similar-to-words-in-a-f)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at lucene ? There's a java and a .net version

http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd load the dictionary of words to a HashMap or "Dictionary", then read the file in line by line or word by word, checking if the map contains the word.

Comment: Sorry this will be far too slow. I'm looking for an algorithm that that can read a text stream and search cost is constant (does not increase as number of words increases). I think what I might be looking for is a Perfect Hash function.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: This is still not as good as an DFA approach that can simply read a text stream as a byte sequence and emit match events.

Comment: Ahh looks like [fgrep](http://ss64.com/bash/fgrep.html) does the job. It implements the [Aho and Corasick string match alg.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)