# is there any method that will find nearest match

Tags: c#, algorithm, string, comparison

I want to compare two strings, such as:

```
 str1 = "this is a dynamic data";
 str2 = "this is a <data_1> data";
```

Is there any method that will find the nearest match? I have used Ternary Search Tree (TST) Dictionary functions. Are there any other ways to do this kind of thing?

Comment: This should make for an interesting read http://stackoverflow.com/q/49263/108847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `Jaccard similarity coefficient`?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

It's easy to implement and gives a good similarity score. You have to tokenize your sentences though ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in BCL that finds nearest match of the string.
But you can roll your own.
read about "**Levenshtein Distance**" on the following [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Answer (score 1):

In am not sure about this thing in C#, but yes that is there in SQL,

```
select difference('this is a dynamic data','this is a dynamic')
```