# Are there any algorithms that would find the closest match to a string from a collection of strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, match

Are there any algorithms that would find the closest match to a string from a collection of strings? For example:

```
string_to_match = 'What color is the sky?'

strings = [
  'What colour is the sea?', 
  'What colour is the sky?', 
  'What colour is grass?', 
  'What colour is earth?'
]

answer = method_using_string_matching_algorithm(string_to_match, strings)
answer # returns strings[1] 'What colour is the sky?'
```

Comment: Define your metrics of "closeness", please.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263/approximate-string-matching-algorithms

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)?

Comment: Why can't you run string matching on each of the strings one by one ?

Comment: 'What color is the ski?'

Comment: @DhruvPathak they're duplicate questions, the distance can be defined as [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @RichardInglis thanks, previous searches on the topic hadn't included the word 'Approximate'. The Wikipedia page looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search terms you're looking for are "string distance algorithms" and "approximate string matching." A quick check of Google turns up interesting options such as:

- Sift3 Distance
- Levenshtein Distance
- Optimal String Alignment Distance
- Damerau-Levenshtein Distance
- Qwerty Keyboard Distance

Some useful links include:

- https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck/wiki/String-Distance-Algorithms
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

As of this writing, Debian-based Linux distributions also include agrep and [TRE-agrep](http://laurikari.net/tre/about/) in their repositories.

Comment: thanks for the keywords and links. I've been using the Ruby Amatch gem which includes Levenshtein http://flori.github.com/amatch/