# Matching 2 strings and allowing a 5% mismatch rate

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I have 2 files with around 100,000,000 lines that need to be compared to each other. As stated in the title I want to compare each line from the files to each other. I have the code below which works absolutely fine, however I wish to adapt it so that if a mismatch occurs during a long match then it's accepted with a mismatch level of 5%.

Below is the function I use for matching the lines of the files.

```
ret1 = []
merging = {} 
def slide_merge(seq1, seq2):
    for i in xrange(min(len(seq1), len(seq2))):
        if seq1[i] == 'N':
            ret1.append(seq1[i])
            print (''.join(ret1))
        elif seq2[i] == 'N':
            ret1.append(seq1[i])
            print (''.join(ret1))
        elif seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
            break
        else:
            ret1.append(seq1[i])
            print (''.join(ret1))
    print ("strings share a longest common prefix of length:", len(ret1), "out of:", len(seq1))
    ret1len = len(ret1)
    merging[''.join(ret1)] = ret1len # Adds details to dictionary
    return merging
```

The below code is how the above function is used within the code and how I get the longest match.

```
while len(rc1u) >= 50: # So matches of 8 are included
    slide_merge(rc1u, rc2wr)      ### rc1u all cut up here so of no further use
    rc1u = rc1u[1:]
merging
max(merging.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
highest = max(merging.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
highest
```

Incase it matters I am using HTSeq to input the files which are genetic sequencing.

So the question is how could I adapt this code or make another code which compares 2 strings and identifies the longest matching sequence from the start whilst allowing for 5% mismatches to occur so for example:

```
string1 = AAAAATTTTTCCCCCGGGGGTTTTT
string2 = AAAAATTTTTCCCCCGGGGATTTTT
```

The code should see that the 2 strings match entirely apart from 1 character but as that is less than 5% of the total the matched region should be stated as:
matched
25

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Sorry will edit to make clearer.

Comment: @Sikorski FWIW, I don't think it's unclear what the question is (unless "how do I modify this to allow up to a 5% difference still count as a match" _isn't_ the question).

Comment: @Michelle that is the question but incase anyone else doesn't get it I have added an example and restated the question at the bottom.

Comment: You probably want the edit distance between two strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460177/edit-distance-in-python

Comment: Isn't this going to take `O(n²)` time? For `n = 1E8`, you're going to have troubles.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between those words and then find the percentage of 'mismatch between those words'.

An example of implemenation is provided [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python).

Let's say that the function computing the distance between two strings is called `dis_lev`, you could evaluate the percentage this way:

```
from __future__ import division

distance = dis_lev(string1, string2)
mismatch_ratio = distance / len(string1)
if mismatch_ratio > 0.05:
    raise MyAwesomeException("Hey ! These things do not match at all !")
```

For example, using your example and the iterative implementation available in the links I've provided:

```
>>> distance = dis_lev("AAAAATTTTTCCCCCGGGGGTTTTT", "AAAAATTTTTCCCCCGGGGATTTTT")
>>> distance
1
>>> mismatch_ratio = distance / len("AAAAATTTTTCCCCCGGGGGTTTTT")
0.04
```

Edit: Depending on your case, you could use another metrics, some are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric)

Comment: I seriously doubt you can compute the Levenshtein distance between files of `100M` in reasonable time. I think a heuristic approach will be more appropriate...

Comment: @CommuSoft how would a heuristic approach be applied?

Comment: @Tom you may be interested by the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49263/approximate-string-matching-algorithms people discussed algorithm that relates to biological data.